# What should i do if I raise for 4th rakat maghrib by mistake?

Tags: salat, mistake

What should I do if I raise up for fourth in Maghreb by mistake and realize this after bending and reciting the supplements?

Answer (score 0):

Prostration of forgetfulness is your solution after tasleem.